# How to Copy/Paste From Mathematica into Excel

Tags: export

Is there a simple way to copy/paste a table of data from Mathematica into Excel? I know I can `Export` the data, but copy/paste would be so much more convenient for a variety of reasons.

I've tried copy/paste from `InputForm`, from `TableForm`, using `Print` to format the output ... but nothing works.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

surprisingly simple.. use `TableForm` or `MatrixForm`

```
 {{1, 2}, {3, 4}} // TableForm
```

Then select the data, right-click, "copy as" "plain text" and paste into an excel cell.

If you have a `MatrixForm` be sure to select only the data, not the brackets.

Comment: This works well and easy to remember, so I mark it "correct". Others should make note that Sjoerd's answer is great, too, but a bit harder to remember IMO.

Comment: If keyboard shortcuts are your thing, you can also do Copy As Plain Text with Control-Shift-C or Command-Shift-C.

Answer (score 23):

I usually do something like:

```
ExportString[myTable,"TSV"]//CopyToClipboard
```

with the table in the variable myTable.

Comment: This is so slick - love it. I ended up marking another correct as it is easier to remember.

Comment: @GregH Glad you like it. If remembering this is an issue you could always use a user defined function with a better name instead and put it in an init.m file. The additional advantage of the method is that it also works on huge tables that you don’t want to have on your screen.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing beats ExcelLink for interacting with Excel. I even figured out how to load Excel files that exceeded the Java Virtual Heap size limit using ExcelLink ([Importing a large Excel file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3836/importing-a-large-excel-file/153527#153527)). That problem may have gone away in 11.3, but it shows kind of things you can do with it.  Of course, you do have to buy ExcelLink, but I couldn't live without it.

I have to admit that Sjoerd's trick is neat.

Answer (score 1):

I simply use the [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImportingAndExportingData.html) function, e.g.

```
Export["data.csv", Table[Table[i*j, {i,10}], {j,10}]]
```

and then open the *temporary* output file in Excel and copy its data. Not the best solution I know, but does the job...

Answer (score 1):

For those that want to avoid mouse clicks at the expense of possibly more keypresses, postfixing `//TableForm//TextCell//CopyToClipboard` can be a quick fix as well:

```
 {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5,6}} //TableForm//TextCell//CopyToClipboard
```

This avoids the need of selecting the output, right-clicking, and choosing "Copy As" > "Plain Text".