# Read a compressed ascii data file?

Tags: import

I would like to write a filter for `Import` to handle data files that are generated by LabView in the LVM format. This should be straightforward, since the format is supposed to consist of comma delimited ASCII text. However, if I read the file in normally, I get junk with a few legible snippets mixed in.

The file can be opened directly in MS Excel, so my guess is that the ASCII data is compressed and being unzipped transparently when it is opened in that program.

```
BinaryReadList["data.lvm", "Character8"]

(* Large output: {P,K,\.03,\.04 ... *)
```

I've posted the output of `BinaryReadList` [here](http://pastebin.com/dFA6tHW9). The original data file can be downloaded [here](https://app.box.com/s/6vlszid53bi5istfl8amzh7p0d5b0g6t).

Are there any facilities available in Mathematica to deal with this kind of data?

Comment: the lvm format itself is not compressed. do you know the history of the file? can you make it available?

Comment: @george2079 I added a download link for the data file.

Comment: @george2079 The first few characters look like the [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)) for a zip file to me: "PK\003\004"

Comment: see what this  does.. http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExtractArchive.html

Comment: @george2079 Interesting: `ExtractArchive` gives me a 4 folders (xl, NI, docProps, and _rels) containing XML files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [standard Excel XLSX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) file. It is not a compressed ASCII file. I don't know why LabView uses the `lvm` extension, it seems weird.  But then I don't know anything about LabView.

Just use

```
Import["data.lvm", "XLSX"]
```

Note: Office Open XML files are actually just ZIP files with a standardized directory structure with XML files inside.  This is why you can unzip it.

Comment: possibly someone saved the file in excel and then gave it the wrong extension.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks, this is indeed the case. After your insights, I found [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1769/20144) helpful for importing the data in a more convenient form.